# Proper initialization and destruction of a C++ array of object pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, constructor, destructor

I want to create an array of pointers to custom objects Image, but I am not sure if I am doing it properly (and I dont have any experience with arrays of pointers). I have a constructor that takes in one image as the first element and the array size, but I don't think I have properly created an array of image pointers. I know it is probably a lot easier, but I do not want to use vectors.

In the header file, I have:

```
class Album {
public:
  unsigned arrmax;
  Image** imgar;
  Image basepic;
```

And in the cpp file I have a constructor:

```
Album::Album(const Image & picture, unsigned max) {
arrmax = max;
basepic = picture; //operator overloaded
imgar = new Image*[arrmax]; //array of Image pointers 
for (unsigned i = 0; i < max; i++) {
   imgar[i] = NULL;
  }
 imgar[0] = &basepic;
}
```

My destructor looks like this:

```
Album::~Album() {
if (imgar != NULL) {
for (unsigned i = 0; i < this->arrmax; i++) {
  if (imgar[i] != NULL) {
    delete imgar[i]; // delete[] or delete??
   } 
  }
 }
}
```

For the destructor, would I also have to do `delete[] imgar` as well after iterating through the elements? Or am I just not deleting the right things?

Comment: You probably want to use a `std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Image>>>` and forget about the manual memory management at all.

Comment: `delete` what you `new` and `delete[]` what you `new[]`. If you neither `new` nor `new[]`, you don't `delete` nor `delete[]`. `imgar[i]` is a pointer to whatever `basepic` is, you don't seem to `new` it. Avoid these kinds of concerns and use smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr` or standard containers.

Comment: Sorry, one indirection too much, `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Image>>` would be enough.

Comment: More than likely what you really need is just a `std::vector<Image>`

Comment: modern c++ programs should never normally use naked pointers, use shared_ptr or unique_ptr.

Comment: To those who close for duplicated of "How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?". Please, read the question: Is not a 2d array; it does not ask for `new`; Is not the same question, the answers are not related neither.
If you don't like the question, find another excuse.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the for loop in the destructor because you want to delete a pointer array created using `new []`.
This alone is sufficient:

```
Album::~Album() {
    delete[] imgar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I understand you prefer some direction/good-practices rather than a direct answer.

Some good practices:

- Try to avoid direct memory management, it is error prone. Whenever you can, prefer smart pointers (unique, shared, weak)
- You may use std::array/std::vector as an improved array, it manage the size and has some other good to have features.
- For array sizes, prefer size_t over "unsigned int"
- Most of the time, the container range loop is more readable and faster.

So your code could be something like this:

```
class Album{
public:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Image>> _imgVect;
    Image basepic;
    ...
};

Album::Album(const Image & picture, unsigned max) {
    _imgVect.reserve(max);
    basepic = picture; //operator overloaded
    // default of unique_ptr is already nullptr

    // Not really a good practice, but without more information
    // of what you are trying, it is the best I could imagine.
    _imgVect[0] = std::unique_ptr<Image>(&basepic, [](Image*){});
}

// Use default destructor
```

> but I do not want to use vectors

Any reason in particular? If you do not want containers, yes: new/delete is your choice. You might still use the smart pointer.

> For the destructor, would I also have to do delete[] imgar as well after iterating through the elements? Or am I just not deleting the right things?

using `delete[]` will delete the array, but not the content which is saved for each pointer in the array. You must use `delete` over each element before to delete all the array with `delete[]`.

You have to be very careful with what you delete, for example, the first element of your array (in your question code) is not a heap allocated object, so trying to delete it will have undefined behaviour (usually a crash).